# p:dataTable with converters/validators. Rows being editted on other than the first page do not stay in edit mode on conversion/validation violation

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, jsf-2.2

Consider any simple [`<p:dataTable>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml) with any JSF validator(s) / converter(s). Given below a cut-down version as an example to reduce complexity.

```
<p:column>
    <p:cellEditor>
        <f:facet name="output">
            <h:outputText value="#{row.value}"/>
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="input">
            <p:inputText value="#{row.value}" required="true"/>
        </f:facet>
    </p:cellEditor>
</p:column>
```

The given `<p:inputText>` is mandatory. Naturally, if a `<p:row>` is edited (using a `<p:rowEditor>`) and the given validation is violated on clicking the link (indicated by a tick mark by default), then the row should stay in edit mode unless the validation passes. This happens correctly only on the first page of `<p:dataTable>`.

If the table has pages and **if a page is changed to other than the first page**, then row which is being edited will go in display mode even though the validation is not satisfied once the edit link is pressed.

Actually, the validation is internally performed correctly but the editing row does not stay in edit mode, if any validation(s) is violated. It goes in display mode as soon as the edit link is clicked. This certainly should not happen.

Coming back to the first page from another page of `<p:dataTable>` would again surprisingly look normal (in short, the expected behaviour happens only on the first page of `<p:dataTable>`).

Is there a solution to this?

Given it a try on PrimeFaces 5.0 and 5.1 alternatively (community releases).

---

**Update :** This does happen in PrimeFaces 5.2 final too (community release).

Comment: Nice catch, I just check my application where I have a similar datatable and the same "bug" happened...

Comment: If someone is willing to create an issue, then please do it. I do not know how to create an issue in the "Defect" category. It goes to a "New Feature" category unnecessarily (as it is certainly a defect and not a new feature). I do not see any option that can be selected to report an issue in other than the "New Feature" category.

Comment: [Reported anyway](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=7569&thanks=7569&ts=1414120795) (I do not know how to put an issue in a defect category).

Comment: I'm having the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30033853/invalidate-primefacess-datatable-row-on-row-edition

Comment: Can you create an answer that it is a bug in PF so that we can mark the other question by @Baderous as a duplicate?

Comment: @Kukeltje : The issue status is still *review/pending*. Besides, I do not have any workaround. Therefore, that question cannot reasonably be marked as duplicate by answering this question without a workaround/solution.

Comment: Issues in PF very often stay Pending/Review and unfortunately, you could not change it to a 'bug', only Project members could. And I disagree that there is no answer to this question. The answer is that it is a bug... The nowhere states in the SO 'guidelines'  that there needs to be a workaround. What will happen now is that there might be even more 'duplicate'  questions, where noone is able to mark them as such. For me stating something is a bug is a valid answer. And if you realy need a more profound answer, I can always say that downloading the source and patching it is a 'workaround'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is no longer reproducible in [PrimeFaces 5.3 final](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/primefaces/primefaces/5.3/) (community release).

**Therefore, I assume it is fixed** irrespective of the issue status (which is "Review") on the [frozen issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=7569&thanks=7569&ts=1414120795).

<sub>Other than that the only solution is to modify the source code, if using that (or higher) version is not an option.</sub>